# Cannot find symbol error Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al ejecutar este programa sacado de un libro. El error es "cannot find symbol". Yo soy estudiante y estoy empezando, por ello no se a que se deba.

Aquí el código:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    class Ejemplo1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Comienta main()...");
        Circulo c = new Circulo(2.0,2.0,4.0);
        System.out.println("Radio = " + c.r + "unidades.");
        System.out.println("Centro = (" + c.x + "," + c.y +") unidades.");
        Circulo c1 = new Circulo(1.0,1.0,2.0);
        Circulo c2 = new Circulo(0.0,0.0,3.0);
        c = c1.elMayor(c2);
        System.out.println("El mayor radio es "+ c.r +".");
        c = new Circulo();
        c = c2.elMayor(c1, c2);
        System.out.println("El mayor radio es "+ c.r +".");   
        VentabaCerrable ventana =
        new VentanaCerrable("Ventana abierta el mundo...");
        CirculoGrafico cg1 = new CirculoGrafico(200,200,200, Color.red);
        CirculoGrafico cg2 = new CirculoGrafico(200,200,200, Color.blue);
        RectanguloGrafico(50,50,450,350, Color.green);
        v.add(cg1);
        v.add(cg2);
        v.add(rg);
        PanelDibujo mipanel = new PanelDibujo(v);
        ventana.add(mipanel);
        ventana.setSize(500,400);
        ventana.setVisisble(true);
        System.out.println("Termina main()...");
    }
    public abstract class Geometria{
        public abstract double perimetro();
        public abstract double area();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola el error "cannot find symbol" significa que estas usando una variable que no fue declarada.

Viendo el código, seguramente se trate de la variable `v` a la cual le haces `v.add(..);` pero no la tienes declarada en ningún lugar.

Comment: Okay, vere si ese es el problema, muchas gracias!